# "pdftk multistamp"-like utility for Postscript?

Tags: pdf, postscript, pdftk

Is there a utility for Postscript files doing the same thing as "[pdftk multistamp](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-multistamp)" for pdf files?

I'm searching for a solution without a ps to pdf conversion, because I'm afraid of a loss of data during the conversion, either in document quality, or things like "output paper tray" information. Maybe I'm wrong, and these informations are preserved during the conversion?

Comment: See http://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2005-May/006956.html

Comment: Thanks. This will certainly help me starting coding the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no, there is no such utility. You can get the same effect by defining a BeginPage or EndPage procedure, however.

Note that *any* conversion (even from PostScript to PostScript) is likely to lose device-dependent information such as tray selection.

Answer (score 0):

Use ghostscript.  Its available for most major operating systems.

Comment: Yes, of course, Ghostscript is able to do great things with Postscript, but apparently not a "merge" like "pdftk multistamp" does with PDF.